# Cypress - auto open devtools focused on console tab

Tags: google-chrome, cypress, google-chrome-devtools

I would like Cypress to open Chrome devtools with the Console tab selected when executing my test suites.

I have seen the approach to set the `--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs` flag as described [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/browser-launch-api#Open-devtools-by-default) to launch devtools via cypress config, but it selects the Elements tab by default. Are there any other args that can be supplied to get the Console tab selected instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can send the key combination Cmd/Ctrl+Alt/Option+J when test is started which opens devTools exactly on Console tab.

```
cy.get('body').type('{command}', {release: false});
cy.get('body').type('{alt}', {release: false});
cy.get('body').type('J');
cy.get('body').type('{alt}{command}');
```